# Adding hoverintent to ajax dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, live, hoverintent

I'm working on a mega dropdown menu that is loaded via ajax. I would like to add hover intent to the menu but I haven't been able to locate a good example of combining .live() with hoverintent it.

I would like to delay the hover for a few seconds to give the other menus a head start on collapsing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li.top-nav-links').live('mouseenter', function() {
           $(this).find('a.top-nav-link-hover').addClass("top-nav-hover");
           $(this).find('div').slideDown(300);
           $(this).css('z-index', 9000 );      
    });

    $('li.top-nav-links').live('mouseleave', function() {
           $(this).find('div').slideUp(function() {
                   $(this).siblings('a.top-nav-hover').removeClass("top-nav-hover");
               });
               $(this).css('z-index', 8000 ); 
    });

});
</script>
```

> Notes: Basically it's an unordered
>   lists that reveals a hidden div inside
>   of it. The z-index reorders the most
>   current hovered drop down to the top

Comment: You could instead of mouseenter and mouseleave just use `.live('hover', function() { do this on mouseeneter }, function() {do this on mouseleave});});`

Comment: I started with hover and slideToggle but because of the complexity in the div that expands hover had issues handling it's location inside the sub navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what ended up working. I'm not totally sure why .live() isn't required because it's loaded Via Ajax. I guess that's what sent me astray.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var overFn = function(){
        $(this).find('a.top-nav-link-hover').addClass("top-nav-hover");
        $(this).find('div.sub').slideDown(300);
        $(this).css('z-index', 9000 );
         return false;
    };

    var outFn = function(){
        $(this).find('div.sub').slideUp(280, function() {
           $(this).siblings('a.top-nav-hover').removeClass("top-nav-hover");
           });
         $(this).css('z-index', 8000 ); 
    }; 

    $('li.top-nav-links').hoverIntent({ 
        over: overFn, 
        out: outFn 
    });

});
```

> **Note:** .live() was required prior to adding hoverIntent.

---

> **Update:** The code above worked on the test site. However, once we moved it over to the
>   live site we needed to make a change because it stopped firing the hoverIntent.
>   and I found this post by *RANDOM.NEXT()* very helpful in finding our resolution --
>   http://bit.ly/D4qr9

**This is the final final code:**

```
jQuery(function()  
{  
    $('li.top-nav-links').live('mouseover', function()  
    {  
        if (!$(this).data('init'))  
        {  
            $(this).data('init', true);  
            $(this).hoverIntent  
            (  
                function()  
                {  
                    $(this).find('a.top-nav-link-hover').addClass("top-nav-hover");
                    $(this).find('div.sub').slideDown(300);
                    $(this).css('z-index', 9000 );
                     return false; 
                },  

                function()  
                {  
                    $(this).find('div.sub').slideUp(280, function() {
                       $(this).siblings('a.top-nav-hover').removeClass("top-nav-hover");
                       });
                     $(this).css('z-index', 8000 ); 
                }  
            );  
            $(this).trigger('mouseover');  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Comment: Seems like a bunch of work to get hoverIntent to work with live.  I had a similar problem but ended up with a non hoverIntent solution using setTimeOut and clearTimeOut... I tried the above code but couldn't quite get it working bug free in my scenerio.  Shame hoverIntent doesn't work with live.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var config = {  
        // put hoverIntent options here    
    };
    $('li.top-nav-links').live('hoverIntent', config, function() {
           $(this).find('a.top-nav-link-hover').addClass("top-nav-hover");
           $(this).find('div').slideDown(300);
           $(this).css('z-index', 9000 );      
    });

    $('li.top-nav-links').live('mouseleave', function() {
           $(this).find('div').slideUp(function() {
                   $(this).siblings('a.top-nav-hover').removeClass("top-nav-hover");
               });
               $(this).css('z-index', 8000 ); 
    });

});
</script>
```